# How to connect two systems (thrift server and client) using serial connection?

Tags: java, thrift

I am a beginner in thrift concept and I want to connect my thrift client to thrift server using serial connection. I am using java on client side.

I already have connected both the client and server using TCP/IP by providing the IP and port of the server to which the client needs to be connected.
Question is how to connect the both on serial connection?
What information do I need to provide in order to establish the connection?

To establish the TCP/IP connection,I have used:

***TTransport transport = new TSocket("xx.xx.xx.xx", xxxxx);***

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write a customized endpoint transport for the serial connection. There is no built-in transport for RS232.

Use one of the existing transports (e.g. the one for sockets) as a model. The [TTransport abstract class](https://github.com/apache/thrift/blob/master/lib/java/src/org/apache/thrift/transport/TTransport.java) consists only of a handful of methods that need to be implemented.

Comment: Does underlying transport needs to be TCP like (guarantee everything) or pure serial can be used and Thrift will take care of trnasport issues?

Comment: We have transports for all kind or more or less reliable physical transports like HTTP, files, named pipes. All of these are covered by a comparingly simple abstraction. In case of a unrecoverable Transport or Protocol issue you throw away the connection and reestablish it, that has been proven the most reliable way to do it.

Comment: OK, so reliable transport is mandatory for correct operation.